# You wouldn't do something, would you?

Tags: question-tags

I saw this form of request (or question) on an Australian tv show:

> **You wouldn't be able to draw me a mud map of that, would you?**

And then the other guy replied:

> **Yeah, sure**

I only understood that it's a form of request because the other guy said "Yeah, sure", and then he did draw the map for him. So, I'm just wondering how common it is to use this form for requests? and is it always understood as a request? for example, if there was no "me" in the question, wouldn't it be that he knows that the other guy can't draw the mud map and is just confirming that?

I'm confused, what differentiates a request from a statement here?

Can I use the following form as a request?

> **You wouldn't be able to send me this report this afternoon, would you?**

or is it better to use the clearer form (at least clearer for me):

> **Can you send me this report this afternoon?**

Comment: It there was no "me" in the question the meaning wouldn't change. Context and tone fill in the blanks, so I would take "You couldn't draw a mud map, could you?" to mean the same thing, with "of that" and "for me" implied from context. Note though that exactly the same sentence with a different tone could change a polite request into an insult.

Comment: Asking in an indirect way for someone to do something ('Would you be able to do X?' or 'Would you mind doing X?) makes it seem less like a command. 'You wouldn't be able to do X, would you?' is even more oblique. This isn't to say that 'Can you do X?' is rude; as nnnnnn says, it depends on the context and your tone of voice.

Comment: This reminds me of the joke about the eagle that swallowed whole a frog, and whilst flying high, the frog emerged from the back end of the alimentary canal, and observing  the height, asked a very relevant question in a similar fashion...

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Answer (score -1):

I think the second one is more common in everyday use, not to mention much more formal than the first option. Although they both technically mean the same thing. You could change it to this (so it sounds a little nicer):

*Could you **please** send me the report this afternoon?*